# Nexus 5 front camera not working

Tags: camera, nexus-5, bugs, google, front-camera

Yesterday my front camera on Nexus 5 stopped working. It doesn't show up in any app (& there's a bug in the new Google camera app - I can switch camera only if the HDR+ is on, but then it's stuck on "Can't connect to camera'). I'm out of options, I already tried: deleting cash, reinstalling camera, safe mode, factory reset... - nothing worked. Anybody got another idea how to get it working? Thanks in advance

Threads I found:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/6RVMvPaF80s
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/MATebxlFYyA﻿

Comment: Take a look at my answer to a similar issue here:

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/camera-doesnt-work-on-nexus-5-running-android-l/96945#96945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:
If you don't have a RMA option like me, it's possible it can be fixed with just disconnecting and reconnecting the front facing camera.

Try deleting cash, reinstalling camera, safe mode, factory reset, etc. before doing this.
Proceed at your own risk!

As shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPuCmfhzgbg)

1. Remove the back of the phone (beginning of the video).
2. Unscrew the top plastic plate (7:15 - 8:10).
3. Disconnect and reconnect front-facing camera flex cable (13:43 - 13:57).
4. Put everything back together and you're done.

Viola!
I hope it helps someone.

UPDATE: It stopped working again and this didn't help anymore. I had to buy a spare part and according to the video above replace it. The repair was succesful though.